# scroll the content of a IFRAME

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a frame on which I am loading a website, for example yahoo.com. Now the question is i don't want want the default scrollbar. i have two links like 'UP' and 'DOWN' for scrolling the content.

Can you please let me know how can achieve this.

The Code goes like this

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="previewBack">
    <div id="previewWrapper">
    <iframe src="http://www.qrr.mobi/?q=uelqqbvi" frameborder="0" id="frame" 

 onmouseover="this.className='scroll'" onmouseout="this.className='noscroll'" 

 class="noscroll"></iframe>

   </div>
<a href="#">UP</a><a href="#">DOWN</a>
</div>
 </body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**jScrollPane** will do that.

http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html

The Demo page shows some "ScrollTo" links like the ones you're asking about...

http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/scrollTo.html

---

**EDIT:**

You're using jQuery, so you don't need the inline JavaScript "onmouseover, etc." within your iFrame element.

Comment: In both of the examples, they are using Div instead of Iframe.

Comment: @Raj:  iframe or div... it doesn't matter.  That plugin is for scrollbars anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the following in the CSS for the iframe class, in order to have the vertical scroll bars go away:

```
.noscroll{
  clear:both;
  overflow:hidden; 
}
```

Comment: yes, i have that. But my question is how to scroll these content without the scrollbar